# MongoDB return first match from $in statement

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB query like;

```
db.Mappings.find({
            "UrlHash" : {
                "$in" : [ 
                    "F0B457493DDE7C53860BB770193848AD", 
                    "0A096439E718BFB7AE77C65B38AA904E", 
                    "8DC5195910E952C181BAF535ACDD2F35"
                ]
            },
            "TopicId" : "3511"
        })
```

Actually what I am trying to do is, bring me first result from collection whichever first matches from $in statement. Since I could not do it, I am sending all possibilities in one shot, get the list and get first result.

So what I want to do is if query matches with F0B457493DDE7C53860BB770193848AD then bring it first and stop, otherwise bring first result from 0A096439E718BFB7AE77C65B38AA904E and so on..

I know I can do separate queries and iterate until I find, but I am just wondering if there is a clever way to do it in one shot.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: you want an ordered $In? Unfortunately the only way is through the aggregation framework by weighting the search terms, not even an $or will do it now

Comment: Yes, that's true, I would like MongoDB to search ordered $in and bring me first result of whichever is matches.

Comment: Unfortunately I must lead you down a dead end road: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7528 this is the ticket for such functionality

Comment: Writing a good iteration function seems like the way to go. Neat question though.

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt exactly answer your question but preserves the order in the list. so you could get the first element in the results as your answer. See additional explanation [here](http://www.kamsky.org/stupid-tricks-with-mongodb/using-34-aggregation-to-return-documents-in-same-order-as-in-expression)

```
    let keys = [
      "F0B457493DDE7C53860BB770193848AD", 
      "0A096439E718BFB7AE77C65B38AA904E", 
      "8DC5195910E952C181BAF535ACDD2F35"
    ]

​    let match = { $match : { UrlHash : { $in : order }, TopicId : "3511" } };

    let addFields = { $addFields : { __order : { $indexOfArray : [ keys, "$UrlHash" ] } } };

    let sort = { $sort : { __order : 1 } };

    db.Mappings.aggregate( [ match, addFields, sort ] );
```